# nodeJS Write integer to buffer using buffer.writeInt16BE

Tags: node.js, buffer, uint16

I want to ask, how to store a number (integer in JS) in buffer using buffer.writeInt16BE().

Assume I have a number such as

```
var a = 40000;
```

40000(10) = 9C40 (16)

how can I store 40000 in buffer of size of 2, so it looks something like:

```
<9c, 40>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `buf.writeInt16BE()` because 40000 is larger than 32768. However if you use `buf.writeUInt16BE()` you can write 40000 to the buffer just fine.

Comment: I am getting an error like: ReferenceError: `writeUInt16BE is not defined`

Comment: Those are [methods](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint16be_offset_noassert) available on the Buffer instance, not global functions.